# Temporary rows for unauthenticated users using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ttl

I'm interested in setting up a postgres table to have an temporary rows which expire after a given time period if that user doesn't "authenticate". In mongo this is relatively easy with the expires property, however postgres seems to have no native option for such a thing.

Basically I would need to store the user in a table, set the record (row) to expire within a given time limit (let's stay for argument sake, 12h) and once that user does authenticate, disable the expiry option.

Would it make more sense to have a table where I have a TTL setup, and once that user authenticates, move the user from the expiry table to the permanent user table?

Answer (score 1):

first option is setting up a cron job, that lets say executes every minute checking if you need to remove any expired rows with smth like

```
delete from t where now()-registered >= interval '12 hours';
```

the second is running the same query on (every) insert/select/update (to reduce cost you can create trigger `WHEN username = current_user` or smth like that....

the first options plus - you don't relay on events in your db. if you create partial index (smth like `create index on... where temp_row = true`) and remove the mark after user authenticates - the check with deletes should be fast enough.

The second's - you don't relay on OS job.

both solutions will require taking care of possible avalanche - letting only one  execution...

Comment: If I'm using a load manager like PM2 and running multiple workers (instances of the same node app) how would you manage the cron job if I'm using something like node-cron?